Understanding Unexpected Spectrum
I have a piezo element with a resonance frequency of 90 kHz. When stimulated it has a time constant of 100 µs. From this model (exp * cos) together with modelled white and pink noise I would expect a spectrum like this:

In reality, however, the spectrum looks more like this (note that the model was run at 2MHz sampling frequency above, and at 15MHz below):

The red part looks like some high frequency oscillations have been coupled in (maybe the piezo chassis is vibrating). However, it is completely unclear to me what is happening before the resonance frequency (green). Why is the spectrum here so flat and the amplitude so large in dB?

The issue here is the resolution bandwidth of your measurement which is limited by the total observation time. I am guessing that your signal capture is on the order of 1 ms, such that if there was no window used in computing the spectrum, the resolution bandwidth as the inverse of that would be 1 KHz. Any DC offset will extend out on the log scale given over that bandwidth since it can't be resolved any tighter in frequency (this effect may be clearer by observing the same plot on a linear frequency scale). The rest of the ripples could be sidelobes from not windowing the FFT or actual signals. Windowing the FFT will significantly reduce false sidelobe artifacts at the expense of increasing the resolution bandwidth further, but this is usually a good trade to make.
With that, if you want to observe the signal down to lower frequencies accurately, you will need to increase the measurement time duration accordingly. However the issue you will ultimately face is the stationarity of the signal you are observing, or rather lack of it if the signal is drifting (you'll end up seeing the average frequency in the FFT over that observation time). Also I do recommend windowing the signal prior to taking the FFT to extend the dynamic range of observation from signal peak to noise floor, and I recommend removing the mean from the signal to avoid having DC spread further into those lower frequency regions due to the resolution bandwidth I mention.
To make accurate measurements of the noise floor as a spectral density measurement, I recommend using the Welch method (which will further trade resolution bandwidth for accuracy in the measurement of wider distributed noise processes) but for measuring narrow band signals I recommend an FFT spectrum. I detail the considerations with that further in DSP.SE #87723.
